# php: How to create a file containing variable definitions

Tags: php, timetable

So first I want to say that I'm pretty new to php & javascript. But anyways, I want to make something like a User Interface (1) where you can write sth into certain fields which will create a string for every field and save it into a file on the server so you can get the values the fields should have from other devices.

This is a little graphic to show you what I want to make:

[image: site-schema]

So I'm wondering if anybody knows if it's possible and how to create the file/load the values from it.

Comment: why reinvent the wheel? http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-ini-file.php

Comment: Why do you want to use a file and not a database?

Comment: @MarcB reinventing the wheel is a great way to learn.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you might want is a database, that way one php function can write those values to a db and then another can retrieve those values whenever.

Answer (score 0):

If u r using mysql then ...
Create a php script that passes  the parameter to database using mysqli_query function (that is saving data in database) and after that the website script can retrieve data from the database. .

Comment: I'm sorry its 'you are'